# How to set/create docker images for application that uses kafka and cassandra

Tags: java, docker, cassandra, dockerfile

I have a java spring boot application.
This application make use of cassandra as data storage and kafka for messaging.
I am using the image for cassandra and zookeeper and kafka locally to run them.

I also created DockerFile for my web app, and build the file to create a image.

My application when run, connect to cassandra database.

When I run the application(intelij), it works fine by connecting to cassandra(running as docker) but when I run docker image locally for the same application, the app image container is not able to connect to cassandra running locally and hence fails.

What do I need to do such that I can run the docker container for the app and also connecting to cassandra.

Comment: How do you specify the connection details to Cassandra in your application ? Meaning which host:port combination are you using? I am asking this because if you are using localhost this will not work as localhost inside the docker container is not the same localhost as your machine.

Comment: @Slacky I understand. Yes I am using localhost. How do I specify the port for cassandra when running as a image ?

Comment: I added the explanation as an answer since I anticipated ```localhost``` would be the issue here. The port should be the port that cassandra uses. The issue here is the hostname and not the port. The cassandra container will answer to the same port as before and can be reached by the other container.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know the exact specifics of your connection details (host:port) that you are using in your application but the most common mistake in this situation is using `localhost`.

`localhost` in the docker container is not the same as localhost when you are starting your application outside the docker container. Therefore when starting the application inside the docker container you have to specify a different hostname for your cassandra deployment.

By default docker will use the container id as the container hostname so you would have to replace `localhost` with your cassandra container id or alternatively start the cassandra container using `--hostname` in order to define a hostname that you wish to use.

In the end a more elegant solution would be to use a docker compose file where the hostname of each service is the service name. This is very helpful for starting together multiple services that "talk" to each other.

You can find everything I explained to you regarding the hostnames of containers [here](https://docs.docker.com/config/containers/container-networking/).

Also [here](https://docs.docker.com/compose/gettingstarted/) you can find a nice intro into docker compose.

```
version: '3'
services:
  web:
    build: .
    ports:
      - "5000:5000"
  redis:
    image: "redis:alpine"
```

In this example the hostnames for each service are **web** and **redis**. You can apply this to your compose file and use the corresponding hostnames for cassandra and kafka.

Comment: Yes I have a docker compose file where I am using to setup kafka, cassandra e.t.c.
So do you suggest that I have a command to run docker-compose up command inside my dockerfile or do you suggest that I refer to cassandra host with the name of the cassandra service specified in docker compose file ?

Comment: Then the only problem I see is the hostname. Just use the name of the cassandra service in your application instead of localhost.